# Standard Oracle Fusion Middleware Installation fails on SOA ManagedServer start due to classpath problems

Tags: oracle-11g, middleware

Trying to install Oracle Fusion Middleware 11gR2 on windows (same thing happens on Linux). I have followed the guidelines provided in the http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/install.1111/e14318/toc.htm

1. Installing the weblogic (11g)
2. Oracle 11g databse installation
3. Running the RCU utility to create schema
4. Installed and copied relevant files for Java Bridge
5. Configure the Fusion Middleware

But i found that the SOA server is not getting up in the enterprise manager its showing as down. When i checked the logs iam getting the following error:

```
oracle.jrf.wls.JRFStartup java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jrf.wls.JRFStartup  
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager.invokeClass(ClassDeploymentManager.java:253)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager.access$000(ClassDeploymentManager.java:54)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager$1.run(ClassDeploymentManager.java:205)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace  

<Jul 7, 2009 4:18:48 PM CEST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000286> <Failed to invoke startup class "SOAStartupClass", java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.bpel.services.common.util.GenerateBPMCryptoKey  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.bpel.services.common.util.GenerateBPMCryptoKey  
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager.invokeClass(ClassDeploymentManager.java:253)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager.access$000(ClassDeploymentManager.java:54)  
at weblogic.management.deploy.classdeployment.ClassDeploymentManager$1.run(ClassDeploymentManager.java:205)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace  

<Jul 7, 2009 4:19:27 PM CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'SocketAdapter' due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: The ra.xml <connectionfactory-impl-class> class 'oracle.tip.adapter.socket.SocketConnectionFactory' could not be loaded from the resource adapter archive/application because of the following error:  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/OracleConnectionFactory.weblogic.application.ModuleException: The ra.xml <connectionfactory-impl-class>  
class 'oracle.tip.adapter.socket.SocketConnectionFactory' could not be loaded from the resource adapter archive/application because of the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/OracleConnectionFactory
at weblogic.connector.deploy.ConnectorModule.prepare(ConnectorModule.java:228)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:387)  
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
<Jul 7, 2009 4:19:27 PM CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'MQSeriesAdapter' due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: The ra.xml <connectionfactory-impl-class> class 'oracle.tip.adapter.mq.ConnectionFactoryImpl' could not be loaded from the resource adapter archive/application because of the following error:  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/OracleConnectionFactory.weblogic.application.ModuleException: The ra.xml <connectionfactory-impl-class> class 'oracle.tip.adapter.mq.ConnectionFactoryImpl' could not be loaded from the resource adapter archive/application because of the following error:  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/OracleConnectionFactory  
at weblogic.connector.deploy.ConnectorModule.prepare(ConnectorModule.java:228)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:387)  
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
<Jul 7, 2009 4:19:27 PM CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'OracleAppsAdapter' due to error  
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/exception/PCResourceException.weblogic.application.ModuleException:  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/exception/PCResourceException
at weblogic.connector.deploy.ConnectorModule.prepare(ConnectorModule.java:238)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:93)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:387)  
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)  
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:58)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/api/exception/PCResourceException  
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)  
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)  
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)  
at weblogic.connector.external.impl.RAComplianceChecker.checkOverrides(RAComplianceChecker.java:972)  
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Can any one please tell me if i have missed any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set StartScriptEnabled=true in $WL_HOME/common/nodemanager/nodemanager.properties and restart the NodeManager.